# OS X Boot extremely slow after installing boot camp (XP)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp, disk-utility, refit

I just installed bootcamp on my 2010 13" MBP, running 10.6.

However, after doing the bootcamp, I have extremely slow boot for my OS X partition, and when I verified the disk in Disk Utility (from a superduper backup clone), it told me that the Mac partition could not be repaired.

I can still boot, it is just *VERY* slow.  Windows boots up nice and fast.

Several potentially relevant details:

- prior to going bootcamp, I migrated to SSD (by ditching the optical drive), here's my [walkthrough](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=10814085&postcount=13). (yes, I did have to put the optical disk back in to install XP, quite annoying).
- Also, one step I didn't take was when I bootcamped, I just rebooted and installed XP, instead of having bootcamp initiate the install... is this bad?
- finally, I did have rEFIt installed prior to both the SSD switch and bootcamp, is this a cause of potential issues? (not attached to it in any way).

Any assistance or avenues for investigation would be very helpful!

Comment: I would definitely re-enable rEFIt as a first diagnostic. Or even try setting OS X as the blessed system by going to **System Preferences > Startup Disk**.

Comment: pattern86, I do think rEFIt is still enabled.  I think OSX is the default startup disk.

Comment: Here are some interesting bits I found in my /var/log/fsck_hfs.log:     Incorrect number of thread records
(4, 14703)  (3 times) and ** The volume Mac HD could not be repaired after 3 attempts.

Comment: I modified my answer based on this info about your fsck log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything interesting in `/var/log/system.log` or `/var/log/kernel.log` from when the slowness happens? Look especially for undefined or generic disk I/O errors.

What exactly did it say was the problem it found that it could not repair?

**Update:**
From the fsck log messages you posted, I think it's time to either invest in Disk Warrior or another advanced HFS+ repair utility, or copy anything you need from the problem volume, erase it, and restore from your backup.

If you go the restore-from backup route, and you back is a disk image, be careful how you do it. Some kinds of restores from disk images can do block-copies for speed, but depending on when this filesystem data structure corruption was introduced, your disk image might have that same corruption, and a block-based restore might restore the same corrupt filesystem data structures onto your disk. You want to opt for a restore method that does more of a file-by-file copy rather than block writes. Come to think of it, if you never did a "Scan Image for Restore..." in Disk Utility, or the equivalent command-line operation in hdiutil or a third-party utility, then you probably can't do a block-copy restore of that disk image anyway, so no worries there.

Comment: I will clarify my subject... the slowdown is in boot.  Perhaps it's doing a journal replay or fsck?  I will investigate the log console and update.

Comment: no entries in /var/log/system or /var/log/kernel that come up interesting... after boot the first entries are vmware and other services.

Comment: I wasn't hoping to hear this, but it looks like I'm going to have to abandon my current XP partition (ie, backup, wipe disk, restore from older backup, then update critical files/apps).  Just wondering whether it was my bootcamp expedition or SSD attempt that might have caused this problem... not sure if Diskwarrior is worth my money as it's unclear if it can fix my problems.

Comment: The fsck log suggested that just your HFS+ (Mac) volume (i.e. just that one partition) had problems, not your GPT/MBR or your whole disk. If you don't want to buy DiskWarrior, you don't have to format your entire disk, just erase the HFS+ partition.

Comment: Spiff, you're correct.  I simply used SuperDuper (CCC would work also) to backup my HFS partition on the spinning disk to my backup drive.  Then I booted from the backup, then erased the original partition, then restored to the newly erased partition.  Once I did this, everything just worked as it was before... refit was blessed and is default boot option; SSD boots fast, HD Mac boots fine, and Windows as well.